# Inject dependency out of startup

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I've a "MyClass" that implements "MyIClass" into a seprated assembly responsable for business logic operations.
MyClass requires in its constructor a class "UserLogger" which is an type that rapresent the user logged with some other useful informations.

So, startup class entrypoint is too early to add my service dependency, so I need to add "UserLogger" implementation in another place, right after login execute through jwt.

is there some in way to accomplish that?

@EDIT
in other words, I would be able to register my IMyService right after the loggin controller is invoked and the instance UserLogged is created, so I'll able to register the UserLogged dependency which is required by IMyService dependency.

Comment: Providing an example of your code would go a long ways towards illustrating your point.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to [Service lifetimes of DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes),Transient,Scoped,Singleton

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the following link I've solved:

https://medium.com/@visualbean/injecting-claimsprincipal-into-service-business-logic-layers-net-core-5a10eb8b6cdb

In this way I am able to build my "UserLogged" through the principal and its claims.